# Avoid duplicate data in array which is inside the recursion

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax, function, recursion

I have a recursive type of function which runs dynamically based on a returned query, now I want to avoid duplicate/redundant data from my array from every recursive loop, I put all returned data from my array.

Here is what I've got:

```
function getbarxAxis() {
 $.ajax({
   url: siteurl+"patients_report/bardata_date",
   type: "POST",
   dataType: "JSON",
   success: function(data) {
     var categories = new Array();
     for (var i in data) {
       categories.push(data[i]["datemonths"]);
       getbarseries(data[i]["datemonths"]);   
     }
   }
 });
}
```

This is my first ajax where it gets all the datemonths, now for example I got two datemonths then the function inside is now recursive, now from the function inside which is the getbarseries, I have an array which stores data in array, now here it is :

```
function getbarseries(month) {
    $.ajax({
      url: siteurl+"patients_report/bardataclinic/"+month,
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "JSON",
        success: function(data) {
          var names = new Array();
          for(var i in data) {
            names.push(data[i]['clinic_name']);
          }

          alert(JSON.stringify(uniqueNames));

        }
    });
}
```

Now first recursion data is for example:

```
Clinic 1, Clinic 2, Clinic 3, Clinic 4
```

Second recursion data is:

```
Clinic 1, Clinic 2, Clinic 3, Clinic 4, Clinic 5
```

I want to have a cleaner which detects duplicate, and if it was being duplicated, it will not be push/add from the array.

So the output that I want from the array is something like this from two recursions:

```
Clinic 1, Clinic 2, Clinic 3, Clinic 4, Clinic 5
```

Answer (score -1):

For simplicity, I am just posting the following code. Should you be able to update your code accordingly.

```
var round1 = ["Clinic 1","Clinic 2"];
var round2 = ["Clinic 2", "Clinic 3"];

var finalround = round1.concat(round2); // Merges both arrays
// ['Clinic 1', 'Clinic 2', 'Clinic 3' ]
```

So grab the first recursion data and the next one and Just **concat**.